# Create a windows 10 start up disk in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: automatic

Ok I have given up trying to get my windows 10 laptop to work correctly. I just want to reset it. I am using my old laptop with ubuntu on it. My plan was to dual boot on the new laptop but I seem to have already messed it up. On the new windows laptop I am in the automatic repair loop. I have tried everything! All the "FIXED" videos. I seen my last chance is to just restart my OS. I already have the windows iso I just can't figure out how to create the start up disk on my flash drive with my ubuntu laptop. I got the new laptop from a friend so I don't have a disk.

Comment: [win10 bootable usb tutorial](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=ubuntu%20create%20win10%20bootable%20drive) try this

Comment: Actually, the only tool that works with the current generation of Microsoft's ISOs is MKUSB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive